# write polling service in node.js with sails.js framework

Tags: node.js, sails.js, pm2

i have project in sails.js, i want to write a polling service that check some record in some interval and after that send email. my example code is:

```
 module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {
    cb();
    var refresh = function() {
        setTimeout(doWork, //someInterval);
    };

    var doWork = function() {
        if (//check some condition) {
            sendEmail();
        }
        refresh();
    };

    doWork();
 }
```

i use pm2 libary and start my project with cluster mode. example code is:

```
pm2 start app.js -i 4
```

this command run app.js in cluster mode with 4 process.
the problem is my polling service run in all process because i run my polling service in config/bootstrap.js file and this is very bad.

my question is how can i run my service once in all process?

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Comment: @MU thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if process is master and then run script only on that case.

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
if(cluster.isMaster) // rest of your service...
```

But for me... This is strange logic... You should queue your tasks to shared db, and when task is pooled remove it from it etc.

Comment: thanks for your response.. but when you run with pm2 all process are fork and its not master. thats why this code is no possible..